# Insert space after 3 characters (SQL Express)

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I'm running SQL Server Express
I have a column with zip codes in the format of 12345
and i need to add a space after the third number like 123 45

Answer (score 4):

Just use `FORMAT()` function

```
SELECT format(12345,'### ##') AS ZIP
```

Will result in `123 45`

```
SELECT format(5, '000 00')
```

Will result in `000 05`

Also if you want 0 as placeholder replace # with 0 in formatting string

Answer (score 1):

This will do it

```
CREATE TABLE #TBL (Zipcode varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #TBL VALUES ('12345')

SELECT 
Zipcode,
LEFT(Zipcode,3)+' '+RIGHT(Zipcode,LEN(Zipcode)-LEN(LEFT(Zipcode,3))) AS NewzipCode

FROM #TBL;

DROP TABLE #TBL
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
select *
    ,CASE 
        when dbo.test.zip LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' then LEFT(dbo.test.zip,3) + ' ' + RIGHT(dbo.test.zip,2) 
        ELSE dbo.test.zip
        END
from test.zip
```

Answer (score -1):

A couple of options:

```
DECLARE @Val VARCHAR(10) = '12345'

SELECT  @Val
,       STUFF(@Val, 4, 0, ' ')
,       CONCAT(LEFT(@Val, 3), ' ', RIGHT(@Val, 2))
,       FORMAT(CONVERT(INT, @Val),'### ##')
```